# Create a time interval that will cause a function to run at a random time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, timer

I am trying to load a random image at a random time.  For some reason this is not randomizing the time, though it does randomize the image.   Any ideas what's wrong?

```
    var randomTime2 = 3000; //initialize the random time with this value to start

setInterval(function(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1);//random num for image

    $('.recent-project2 img').fadeTo('slow',0,function(){
            var randomImg = "img/recent-projects-"+randomNum+".jpg";

            $('.recent-project2 img').attr('src',randomImg);
            $('.recent-project2 img').fadeTo('slow',1);

        });
    randomTime2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);//reset random time
    return randomTime2; //return random time
    },randomTime2);
```

Comment: You may need to do a `clearInterval` first, and then set it again. From having played with `set/clearInterval` a bit, it's a bit of a pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval` call will just add your function and the required interval to an internal table to remember to call your code when the expected delay period passed. Note however that even if you change the variable used to specify the interval this will have no effect on the internal table: that value has been read when you called `setInterval` and it's now stored.

To randomize the callback time give your function a name and just use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`:

```
function MyCallback() {
    ...
    setTimeout(myCallback, new_delay);
}

setTimeout(myCallback, first_delay);
```

with this approach at each call you can decide a different delay before next call.

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTimeout` and re-trigger at the end of the function with a random time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the value of randomTime2 inside the function as it's pass by value, not reference.

`setInterval(someFunction, someNumberValue)`

This line of code will call *someFunction* every *someNumberValue-miliseconds*. The value is not updated dynamically.

There's lots of ways you could make this work, but I suggest simply using [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting) and making the end of someFunction call it again. For instance:

```
//psudo-code, might not actually run, just showing you the general idea.
var someFunction = function(){
    console.log("Whatever.");
}

var repeatFunction = function(){
    someFunction()
    var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(repeatFunction, Math.random()*10000);
}

repeatFunction(); //Starts the loop.
```